# what does this mean return($var & 1);

Tags: php

in PHP in the line below `return($var & 1);` What does this mean, what does the & mean in this context?

```
<?php
function test_odd($var)
{
return($var & 1);
}

$a1=array("a","b",2,3,4);
print_r(array_filter($a1,"test_odd"));
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` (ampersand) operator does bitwise `AND`.

If `$var` is **odd** it returns `1`, otherwise `0`.

Let's say `$var = 13` , that in binary is `1101` (because `13 = 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^0`).

When you do `1101 & 0001` you get `0001`. So you can either get `1` if `$var` has its last bit 1 (meaning it's odd) or `0` if `$var` has 0 as the last bit, meaning that `$var` is written as a sum of powers of two, without 2^0` meaning its even.